# How is cross-correlation related with orthogonality?

Tags: cross-correlation, statistics, linear-prediction

In linear prediction we can say that in case of optimum linear predictor the error with be orthogonal to data. And when we derive minimum mean square error for $\underline{y} = \mathbf{a}\underline{x} + \underline{b}$ case we find following relation

> $\xi = \sigma^2_y (1 - \rho_{xy} )^2$

Where $\rho_{xy} $ is correlation coefficient and if we talk about cross correlation $r_{xy}(k,l)$ of zero mean and uncorrelated random variables x and y, then how does this conclude that if $r_{xy}(k,l)$ will be then the signals will be orthogonal?

Comment: What is the relationship between $\rho_{xy}$ and $r_{xy}(k,l)$ ? I'm assuming $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient and $r$ is the cross correlation, but it would be good to spell this out.

Comment: I apologize for ambiguity in the question, I edited it. I hope it is not missing anything now.

Comment: No need to apologise!  Thanks for the edit. It's much clearer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you mean the cross-correlation at lag zero. Well take an Hilbert space $H$ (i.e. a metric space in which you can define a scalar product $\langle\cdot ,\cdot\rangle$). Then $x,y\in H$ are orthogonal if $\langle x,y\rangle=0$, by definition.
If your Hilbert Space is $L_2(\mathbb{R})$ (the space of real square integrable functions) then the scalar product of $f,g\in L_2(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as
$$
\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \overline{f(t)}g(t) dt
$$
If the signals are assumed to be ergodic, which is actually a costumary assumption, then the cross-correlation is simply a sliding scalar product, you have
$$
\text{corr}(f,g)(\tau) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\overline{f(t)}g(t+\tau) dt
$$
hence
$$
\text{corr}(f,g)(0) = \langle f ,g \rangle
$$
and uncorrelation means orthogonality.
The same applies for discrete time signals in $l_2$

Comment: Correlation is, more generally, $E[\overline{f(t)}g(t+\tau)]$. The definition you're using can only be used if $f$ and $g$ are ergodic.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing it out! I assumed implicitly that ergodicity was an assumption on the signals

Comment: Most people do. I gave this a + 1, but thought we should mention the ergodicity piece.

Comment: I added a piece saying that this holds under ergodicity assumption